# *ngIf doesnt work all the time

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

Page-not-found.component.ts

```
import { FormsModule, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { SplitButtonModule } from "primeng/primeng";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-not-found',
  templateUrl: './page-not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-not-found.component.css']
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

page-not-found.component.html

<p *ngif=true>
  page-not-found works!
</p>
```

the problem is `*ngif` is not working. I have restarted my system and cleared cache. I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
> Property binding ngif not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("[ERROR->]<p *ngif=true>
>   page-not-found works!
> </p>
> ```

Comment: `<p *ngIf=true>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
<p *ngIf="true">
  page-not-found works!
</p>
```

`*ngIf` is correct not `*ngif`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have angular syntax like *ngIf, [value=], or (change) the opposite end of equation should probably be wrapped in quotes. That tells angular to look in the component for your value. So I recommend you put a field in your component like this:

```
truthy = true;
```

and then:

```
<p *ngIf="truthy">
  page-not-found works!
</p>
```

If you don't wrap it in quotes, it assumes its a string literal and that probably wont give you the results you want.